# Xperia Z3 Usb debug mode doesn't work at Windows 7 Home Premium x64

Tags: android, debugging, sony, sony-xperia

I have an Xperia Z3 (D6603), and tried to connect at debug mode to my computer with Windows 7 Home Premium x64 and it doesn't recognize it, but without debug mode at device it does it; even the PC Companion doesn't recognize the Z3 device when is in debug mode.

I also downloaded the USB driver for the Z3 from 
(http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/xperia-z3-driver/)
and tried to install from Device Administrator but doesn't recognize for the Z3. I installed the driver "manually" from System Symbol but when try install the Z3 still unrecognize it.

I also have an Xperia ZL, i activated the debug mode, plugged and it worked.

Please tell me what can i do to fix this, thank you very much.

Update 1: I tried install the downloaded driver without debug mode and it works, only happens with debug mode activated. I forgot mention that my device is encrypted, maybe can disturb with debug mode.

Update 2: I reinstalled the OS using PC Companion and formated the Micro SD, also tried without encrypt the system and doesn't work. Also i installed the drivers downloaded published at November 21, i used DPInst.exe.

I really need help with this issue, but Sony doesn't answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I let the problem some weeks, i worked with the ZL. But i don't have other machine for work, so i decided use a VM, and it works fine.

I suppose i have problems with some drivers at the host machine.

So, if you have my problem, use another machine :-), if can't, virtualize.

Comment: I don't agree that the accepted answer should be to use a different machine. This makes no sense. I have the same issue with the driver and I am completely stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Try to setup the drivers with flashtool [flashtool.net](http://flashtool.net) and go to the development settings from the device and clean the settings from USB Debugging. Then try it again.